# Artifactory maven remote repo requires authorization

Tags: maven, artifactory

We are using Artifactory 5.4.6.

Global setting "Allow Anonymous Access" is turned ob

I have created a couple of remote maven repos.
But when i am trying to download artifact it requires authorization and only after that download starts.

Also i've noticed that we have same problem with all maven repos. And only with maven.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your maven setting.xml entries

Comment: @Afgan We are using default settings and have no settings xml file. Can it be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Soloviev As per your question there is some authorization issue, and repository autorization(credential) need to set in maven setting.xml, you need to provide  
 <servers>
    <server>
        <id>localplatform</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
    </servers>
In setting.xml, it might be a cause

Comment: @Afgan so there is no fully anonymous access to repo in maven repos? Only using settings.xml gives us "anonymous" access?

Comment: anonymous access can be given to repository, but i think who created your repository not given read permission(download) to anonymous user.

Comment: Yes. That helped. Thank you!

Comment: please refer ans and check it correct so that other will can take advantage of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question there is some authorization issue, and repository autorization(credential) need to set in maven setting.xml, you need to provide

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>localplatform</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

In setting.xml, it might be a cause.
For you comment question -

Ques- there is no fully anonymous access to repo in maven repos? Only using settings.xml gives us "anonymous" access?

Ans- anonymous access can be given to repository, but i think who created your repository not given read permission(download) to anonymous user

I hope that help you.